# WebDriver Problem, I can't open a google browser

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I've been doing some programs to automate in web using seleniumlibrary and google chrome, but recently I had a serious problem with WebDriver.

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

I've checked a lot of posts with similar conflicts , in every post that I check the people mentions "**use options like --no-sandbox  --headless .... etc**", and that is rigth! this works!
but when I use --headless my browser can show how is automated my process, this is very important to me to analyze every step in the process(I take Screen shots in every step). So this process doesn't work to me.

**================== I HAVE TRIED ================**

1. Update my google chrome version and my chrome driver(81--->83)
2. Downgrade my google chrome version and chrome driver(83--->79)
3. Use --no-sandbox and --headless(they work but I need to see the visual procedure in the window)
4. Build/Update SUID

I realized these points but always is presented the same problem ...

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
>   Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.   (unknown error:
>   DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process started from
>   chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so
>   ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

**I would like to know how to solve this and help other people if they have the same problem**